# break inner loops and pass control to outermost loop in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, break, csvreader

Here is what I am looping through complex nested dictionaries inside a list called **adm2_geonames**. I then have a csv file whose `line[1]` needs to searched inside **adm2_geonames**. Once found, I want to break the loops for **adm2_geonames** i.e. starting from
`for dic in adm2_geonames:` and pass the control to `for line in csvReader:` for next keyword, until all in the csv are read.
I am confused about setting the scope for break statement. I have tried putting multiple break statements also for each inner loop. Seems, not the right approach.
Please I am a beginner python learner, so please be patient if my question is naïve.

```
coords = []
with open('ADM2_hits.csv') as csvFile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvFile)
    next(csvReader)
    for line in csvReader:
        keyword = line[1]
        for dic in adm2_geonames:
            for key in dic:
                if(key == "geonames"):
                    for x in dic[key]:
                        if(keyword == x['name']):
                            line.append(x['lat'])
                            line.append(x['lng'])
                            coords.append(line)
                            break
print(coords)
```

Comment: Why are you iterating over dicts when you know which key you want to use? `line.append(dic['geonmes']['name']['lat'])`, etc.

Comment: Maybe every some dicts don't have that key?

Comment: @alexpdev Then you can simply catch the resulting `KeyError` and continue.

Comment: @chepner Yup or you could use an `if key in dict` statement too. I didn't say it was a good reason... just a reason

Comment: And my question was meant to draw attention to the fact that there *isn't* a good reason to iterate over the dict like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use an `else:` block to capture the case in which the inner loop was not broken (in which case you want to `continue`), followed by a `break` to break the outer loop if the `else` hasn't already continued it:

```
coords = []
with open('ADM2_hits.csv') as csvFile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvFile)
    next(csvReader)
    for line in csvReader:
        keyword = line[1]
        for dic in adm2_geonames:
            for x in dic["geonames"]:
                if(keyword == x['name']):
                    line.append(x['lat'])
                    line.append(x['lng'])
                    coords.append(line)
                    break
            else:
                continue
            break
print(coords)
```

Note that you can eliminate some of that inner looping by just going straight to `dic["geonames"]` instead of looping over the entire dictionary; the whole point of dictionaries is that you can jump straight to a given entry by its key instead of having to search the whole thing iteratively.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need all these loops in the first
place, which means you don't need `break` at all.

```
coords = []
with open('ADM2_hits.csv') as csvFile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvFile)
    next(csvReader)
    for line in csvReader:
        keyword = line[1]
        for dic in adm2_geonames:
            try:
                line.extend(dic['geonames']['name'][k] for k in ['lat', 'long'])
                coords.append(line)
            except KeyError:
                continue
```